# After install ARM and gapps in Genymotion the Google Play doesn't show

Tags: android, genymotion

I've try every tutorial available to install GApps in genymotion and almost every combination but always I got the same issue, after install the ARM, the signed gapps and reboot the emulator doesn't show the Google Play. Any idea?

Please help me.

Regards.

Comment: I've followed http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952 and downloaded gapps from CM 11 : http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#gappsCM11

Be sure to have the installation box each time when you drag & drop on genymotion the ARM & for gapps.

Comment: install ARM, reboot, install gapps, reboot. i do it like that

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. This is not programming related. Try [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) instead.